# Ionic Angular 90809 error when deploying to Apple

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, itms-90809

I did quite a research on this one, and even though it is a very common issue none of the solutions worked for me so I keep getting the dreaded:
`ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability`

My configuration is this:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 4.2.0, windows 4.4.2
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.5
   OS     : macOS Catalina
   Xcode  : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c
```

Plugins:

```
com.verso.cordova.clipboard 0.1.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-clipboard 1.3.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-crop 0.3.1 "CropPlugin"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.6.3 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 7.0.2 "BarcodeScanner"
uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter 1.1.1 "sqlite porter"
```

Could anyone identify something that screams "this one uses UIWebView and you should change it!" ?

UPDATE:

In order to fix the issue I followed these steps:

- Made sure that `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` was in version >= 5.0.0
- Added

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    ...
</platform>
```

To config.xml

- updated ionic `npm install -g ionic@latest`
- updated cordova `npm install -g cordova@latest`
- updated ionic scripts `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest`
- Then removed the iOS platform `ionic cordova platform rm ios`
- Re-added the iOS platform `ionic cordova platform add ios`
- and rebuild it `ionic cordova prepare ios`

Comment: what cordova ios version are you using?? Run command:  `ionic cordova platform ls` and post result

Comment: These: 

`Installed platforms:
  android 8.1.0
  ios 4.2.0
  windows 4.4.2
Available platforms: 
  browser ^6.0.0
  electron ^1.0.0
  osx ^5.0.0`

Comment: Update your iOS `4.2.0` to `5.1.0` or later. here is the list of Version https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/releases.
I would recommend you to use most Latest version i.e 6.

Comment: This ^^ is what fixed my issue. Also keep an eye for duplicate plugins like clipboard or console.

Comment: @MDompekidis, Could you also post the set of steps you have done to fix the issue? A lot of people are facing this issue and your steps might help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed my app for the exact issue recently and Here are the steps I have followed to fix the issue:

1) Ensure your `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` is updated to the latest version `5.0.0`. You need to run these two commands to do that.

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

2) Ensure your `cordova-ios` is updated to the latest version `6.0.0`. Run this command to update it.

```
npm install cordova-ios@latest --save
```

3) Check your `package.json` to see if the versions are updated for both `cordova-ios` and `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`.

4) Ensure you add `WKWebViewOnly` preference to `config.xml` file.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    ...
</platform>
```

5) This is the most important step. Ensure you remove the `ios` platform and add it again. Run these commands to remove and add the ios platform.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Now, when you build the ios app and publish it to the app store, you can see the issue will be fixed.